# マルチインデックスのDataFrameに、複数の列をまとめて追加する方法

Tags: python, python3, pandas

列がマルチインデックスなDataFrameへ、
複数の列を、ループを利用せずに、まとめて追加することできないでしょうか？

参考にしたサイト：https://www.fixes.pub/program/312227.html

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        ['a', 10, 'あ', 11],
        ['b', 20, 'い', 21],
        ['c', 30, 'う', 31] ],
    index=['aa', 'bb', 'cc'],
    columns=[['X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y'], ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B']],
)
print('◇元データ')
display(df)

df_expected = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        ['a', 10, 1000, 'あ', 11, 1100],
        ['b', 20, 2000, 'い', 21, 2100],
        ['c', 30, 3000, 'う', 31, 3100] ],
    index=['aa', 'bb', 'cc'],
    columns=[['X', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C']],
)
print('◇期待する変換結果')
display(df_expected)

print('↓↓↓[参考]値の変更ならまとめてできる')
df.loc[:, (slice(None), 'B')] = df.loc[:, (slice(None), 'B')] * 100 # ←値の変更ならまとめてできる。
display(df)
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 参照している fixes.pub というサイトは StackOverflow のコンテンツを機械翻訳しているサイトのようです。 / 参照しているページも "質問" で止まっているので、お手本とするなら別のサイトを当たった方が良さそうです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

print(pd.__version__)
# 1.4.0

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        ['a', 10, 'あ', 11],
        ['b', 20, 'い', 21],
        ['c', 30, 'う', 31] ],
    index=['aa', 'bb', 'cc'],
    columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['X', 'Y'], ['A', 'B']]),
)

level = df.columns.get_level_values(0).unique()
df[[(i, 'C') for i in level]] = np.array([[1000, 2000, 3000], [1100, 2100, 3100]]).T
df = df[level]

pd.set_option('display.unicode.east_asian_width', True)
print(df)
#
    X             Y          
    A   B     C   A   B     C
aa  a  10  1000  あ  11  1100
bb  b  20  2000  い  21  2100
cc  c  30  3000  う  31  3100
```

Answer (score 0):

`df['X', 'C'] = [1000, 2000, 3000]`のようにカラムを指定して追加できます。
この方法では末尾に追加されるので、期待する変換結果にするには`sort_index`で整列が必要です。

参考資料: [Pandas: add a column to a multiindex column dataframeの回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16089219)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        ['a', 10, 'あ', 11],
        ['b', 20, 'い', 21],
        ['c', 30, 'う', 31] ],
    index=['aa', 'bb', 'cc'],
    columns=[['X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y'], ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B']],
)

# カラム追加
df['X', 'C'] = [1000, 2000, 3000]
#df['Y', 'C'] = [1100, 2100, 3100]
df['Y', 'C'] = df['X', 'C'] + 100   # こんな書き方もできる
df = df.sort_index(axis=1)

print('◇元データ')
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

以下の２通りの方法で、列がマルチインデックスなDataFrameに、まとめて列が追加できること理解/確認できました。
ありがとうございました。

方法①：df[ [列のtuple, 列のtuple, 列のtuple, ...] ] = 追加する列をまとめたデータフレーム
方法②：df[ Level0列名, Level1列名, ... ] = 追加したいシリーズ
さらに、df = df[level]や、df.sort_indexで、列の順番を整理すること。

pd.concat + df.sort_indexでもできました。勉強になりました。